# How do i get my error messages to fade out? in RubyOnRails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fadeout

The error i want to show

```
flash[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
```

I've tried

```
$(document).ready( function() {// When the Dom is ready
    $('.error').hide();//Hide the div
    $('.alert').hide();
    $('.notice').hide();
    $('.success').hide();
    $('.info').hide();

    $(".error").fadeOut(2000); //Add a fade out effect that will last for 2000 millisecond
    $(".alert").fadeOut(2000);
    $(".notice").fadeOut(2000);
    $(".success").fadeOut(2000);
    $(".info").fadeOut(2000);

});
```

with no success.. I have included the javascript file

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.3.2' %>
```

Comment: Are the errors loaded dynamically?

Comment: There is jQuery 1.6.2, but that doesn't matter, open up Console you should see if there are any errors, this should, by itself, work. Check you HTML also (if it has correct class value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have a way to get the error message.

```
flash[:error] = "Invalid username/password combination."
```

just outputs raw text.

```
 flash[:error] = "<div class='error'>Invalid username/password
 combination.</div>"
```

wraps it in a container.

then you can just use jQuery to fade the container out.

```
$(".error").fadeOut(2000);
```

Comment: Sorry Ahmet, the mark down didn't display correctly ... I readjusted it to show the wrapping DIV container.